# Difference among mavenCentral(), jCenter() and mavenLocal()?

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Actually, I am studying on `build.gradle` file. In some cases, I got that sometimes they are using `mavenCentral()`, `jCenter()` and `mavenLocal()` in repositories section. Sometimes they also using URL. So some question arises in my mind?

> i) Difference among mavenCentral(), jCenter() and mavenLocal()?
>
> ii) Which one should I use most?
>
> iii) Is there any performance related issue?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Actually, all 3 are Maven repository. We use these maven repositories to our build by using its URL address or its location in the local file system.

**By using URL:**

```
repositories {
    maven { url("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
}
```

**By using local file system:**

```
repositories {
    maven { url '../maven-repo' }
}
```

**Gradle has three “aliases”** which we can use when we are adding Maven repositories to our build. These aliases are:

1. mavenCentral():

---

The mavenCentral() alias means that dependencies are fetched from the [central Maven 2 repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2).

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

The URL used to access this repository is https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/. The name of the repository is MavenRepo.

2. jcenter():

---

The jcenter() alias means that dependencies are fetched from the [Bintray’s JCenter Maven repository](http://jcenter.bintray.com/)

3. mavenLocal():

---

The mavenLocal() alias means that dependencies are fetched from the local Maven repository.

### Resource Link:

1. [Gradle: Dependency Management](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-dependency-management/)
2. [Maven RepositoryHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html)

---

### Jcenter vs. mavenCentral

jcenter() and mavenCentral() is a repository for the Gradle plugin in Android Studio

Earlier versions of Android Studio used mavenCentral(), and after some time, it switched to jcenter.

This is because jcenter() is superior to mavenCentral() in terms of performance and memory footprint:

- Jcenter is the world's largest Java repository
- Jcenter through the CDN service, using the **https protocol**, highly
  secured, and Android Studio 0.8 version mavenCentral() using the **http
  protocol**
- **Jcenter is a superset of mavenCentra**l, including many additional
  jars
- **Jcenter performance is better than mavenCentral**
- mavenCentral will automatically download many IDE-related indexes,
  and these are used less often which are not required.

Resource Link：
https://www.jianshu.com/p/bce437eeb3d3

---

Last Update:  [**Into the Sunset on May 1st: Bintray, JCenter, GoCenter, and ChartCenter**](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/)

[image]

### Update: 24-02-2021 of [Android Developers Page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration):

[image]

**Announcement Link:** https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

**Maven Central Link:** https://maven.apache.org/repository/index.html

**Work Around:**

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    
//  jcenter()       // <- remove it
    mavenCentral()  // <- add it
    
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/" }
}
```

Comment: JFrog's Bintray Jcenter maven repository... The worst/ confusing name I have heard in a long time... 

Comment: MavenCentral gives more guarantees that the artifacts won't change. Bintray allows maintainers to overwrite existing artifacts, which is convenient but can ultimately be leveraged by malicious users.

Comment: Now jcenter is scheduled to be shut down time to go back to maven central

Comment: These lines  maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/" } fixed problem when adding external library after adding mavenCentral() .. Thanks

Comment: Our man here comes in and makes us feel as if `jCenter` is ultimate. And then informs us about its sunsetting with an extended mix of suggesting us to use `mavenCentral` going forward. LOL. 

Comment: @oleksii I am having this line in my project 
maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }

Do I need to replace it with the urls given in this answer?

Comment: hey @JarinRocks I am not too sure... I've edited the answer but it was a while ago and I don't remember what was the resolution. It could also have changed. Maybe the original author would know, try pinging SkyWalker.

Comment: Thanks for that update. I just saw a prompt in Android Studio that center() had been deprecated and this explained things for me. I've replaced the respective lines with mavenCentral().

Answer (score 12):

As per [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration) page -

**JCenter deprecation and end of service**

JFrog, the company that maintains the JCenter artifact repository used by many Android projects, recently announced the deprecation and upcoming retirement of JCenter. According to the [announcement](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/), JCenter will allow downloads of existing artifacts until February 1, 2022.

Developers who publish artifacts on JCenter should start migrating their packages to a new host, such as [Maven Central](https://maven.apache.org/repository/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

> UPDATE: To better support the community in this migration, JFrog has extended the JCenter new package versions submission deadline through March 31st 2021.
>
> To clarify, the JCenter repository will keep serving packages for 12 months **until February 1st 2022**. Only the JCenter REST API and UI will be sunsetted on May 1st 2021.

Comment: They claim to be committed to being read-only, but in reality they have become very unreliable. certain binaries we use have been inaccessible through them for over two weeks now, meaning they are an unacceptable source moving forward.