# What is the difference between google() and mavenCentral() in project level gradle file in an android project?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

At the project level, the **Gradle file** of an android project contains **google()** and **mavenCentral()** inside the repository block.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have read a related answer [Difference between google() and maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467561/difference-between-google-and-maven-url-https-maven-google-com), but it doesn't describe about **mavenCentral()**. That answer is based on *google()* as a replacement of *maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }*. But in my case **google()** and **mavenCentral()** both are used alongside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between google() and maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467561/difference-between-google-and-maven-url-https-maven-google-com)

Comment: No, that doesn't answer my question. That doesn't describe mavenCentral(). mavenCentral() is a new replacement for jCenter().

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726435/difference-among-mavencentral-jcenter-and-mavenlocal

Comment: But that doesn't say any difference with google().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're different Maven artifact repositories, hosted by different entities, with different purposes.

`google()` is Google's official Maven repository, where we host Google first-party libraries.  This includes the AndroidX libraries, Jetpack Compose, Firebase, Play Services, Material, etc.  You can browse what's hosted there online [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html).

Maven Central is hosted by Sonatype, and allows anyone to upload their projects' artifacts to it.  You can read about how to publish there [here](https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html) and search the repository [here](https://search.maven.org/).