# How do I " SDK 30 and Android 10" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I update the project, this message appears in Android Studio,
I want to build the project in the environment "SDK 30 and Android 10",
But I don't know how to do it.

**gradle wrapper properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

**build gradle project**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() }
    
    dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'  }}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build gradle App**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.codev2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'me.iwf.photopicker:PhotoPicker:0.9.12@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.krokyze:ucropnedit:2.2.1-native'
    implementation 'com.github.duanhong169:colorpicker:1.1.6'



}
```

When I update the project, this message appears in Android Studio,
I want to build the project in the environment "SDK 30 and Android 10",
But I don't know how to do it.

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COiau.png)

Comment: The error says a library cannot be found, add the repositories. I don't think it has something to do with android 10

Comment: How can I do that.
I tried many solutions but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mavenCentral()` (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726436/11880323)) is missing from your `build.gradle`.

Your gradle.build file should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'  }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

As the [project](https://github.com/donglua/PhotoPicker) seems to be deprecated (they recommend [this](https://github.com/zhihu/Matisse) other), if this doesn't work, you'll need to download the library and add it manually to the project `lib` folder.

Comment: It doesn't work ... What is way to download it?

Comment: Did you sync gradle after editing the file?

Comment: Yes. I did & I cleaned the project

Comment: OK, so it seems the library was using JCenter https://github.com/donglua/PhotoPicker/issues/174 which is now deprecated and may not work always (or maybe the author deleted it). So the only way would be to download the Github project and either compile it or add the files manually to your project. You can also check out the other project https://github.com/zhihu/Matisse which I tested and works (but also seems to use JCenter).

Answer (score 0):

Go To `SDK Manager > SDK Tools`

check `Show Package Detail`
and install `SDK Tools 30`

[see on here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Itf8.png)

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried it, but the same error appears

Comment: Upgrade gradle version to latest