# I got error on running first flutter project

Tags: flutter, maven, gradle, jar, classpath

I'm new in flutter.
I created a flutter project and didn't do any changes.
just create and run in vs code.
but it showed me these errors.
why it gave me errors?
what went wrong?
I want to know the reason.
flutter version is 3.3.10 channel stable.
these pictures are about,
[SDK Platforms](https://freeimage.host/i/H77ZKSS) , [SDK Tools](https://freeimage.host/i/H77ZdP4), [SDK Update sites](https://freeimage.host/i/H77ZHoG)

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G9880 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find builder-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.1.2/builder-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find repository-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:repository:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/30.1.2/repository-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find builder-test-api-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/7.1.2/builder-test-api-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find bundletool-1.8.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.0/bundletool-1.8.0.jar
> Could not find aapt2-proto-7.1.2-7984345.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.1.2-7984345).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.1.2-7984345/aapt2-proto-7.1.2-7984345.jar
> Could not find crash-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/30.1.2/crash-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find tracker-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/30.1.2/tracker-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find shared-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/30.1.2/shared-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find databinding-compiler-common-7.1.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/7.1.2/databinding-compiler-common-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find databinding-common-7.1.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/7.1.2/databinding-common-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find baseLibrary-7.1.2.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/7.1.2/baseLibrary-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find layoutlib-api-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/30.1.2/layoutlib-api-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto/30.1.2/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-gradle-proto/30.1.2/android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find builder-model-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/7.1.2/builder-model-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find dvlib-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/30.1.2/dvlib-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find common-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:common:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/30.1.2/common-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
> Could not find jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar
> Could not find apkzlib-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/7.1.2/apkzlib-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
> Could not find protos-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/30.1.2/protos-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find core-proto-0.0.8-alpha07.jar (com.google.testing.platform:core-proto:0.0.8-alpha07).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/testing/platform/core-proto/0.0.8-alpha07/core-proto-0.0.8-alpha07.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `mavenCentral()` inside buildscript{...} and allprojects{...} inside `/android/build.gradle` file like this below:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // <- HERE
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // <- AND HERE

        maven{ url 'http://download.flutter.io' }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Feel free to let me know if this works or not; you can learn more about the different maven repos here: [Difference among mavenCentral(), jCenter() and mavenLocal()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726435/difference-among-mavencentral-jcenter-and-mavenlocal)

Comment: mavenCentral() is already added in /android/build.gradle. but problem still on