# Could not create task ':shared_preferences_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'am trying to build a signed apk from my flutter app, but when I go to: tools > Flutter > Open Android module in Android Studio to generate my apk on the build I'm getting the following error:

```
  Could not create task ':shared_preferences_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    this and base files have different roots: D:\Codes\GitProjects\mediunix-flutter\build\shared_preferences_android and C:\tools\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_android-2.0.10\android.
```

And:

```
* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not create task ':shared_preferences_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\Codes\GitProjects\mediunix-flutter\build\shared_preferences_android and C:\tools\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_android-2.0.10\android.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:160)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.apply(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:133)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.apply(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:111)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$0(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:91)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    ...
```

How can I solve this?

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71734846/13978447 Fixed it for me