# Gradle sync failed: Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'. This and base files have different roots

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

When I pressed on the build This is the error I am getting:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
                this and base files have different roots: E:\flutter\peak_property\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.5\android. (1 m 11 s 576 ms)
```

This is my App Level build Gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.peak_property"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '6.7.1'
}
```

This is my Project-level build.Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I fixed this problem by

1. running `flutter clean`
2. then synchronize project with gradle files again in android studio

Comment: This works for me. Also please note that if you have a nested `example` Flutter project then you will also have to run the clean command for it.

Answer (score 13):

open Android -> build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

change your version to this. works fine.

Comment: After updating the flutter pubsec file, in the android build failed, so i changed classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' and build created successfully.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.5` is not yet compatible with gradle version >= 7.0.0.

So all you can do is downgrade your gradle version or wait for a fix in the library.

Comment: I was facing this problem for a long time, finally a sensible answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the gradle version from 7.0.0 to 7.0.3 and also kotlin version which is ext.kotlin_version = 'latest_version' and now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

Change your project path to the same drive as your profile files is.

So, just move your project from `D:\Projects\Name` to `C:\Projects\Name` if your `C:\Users\Username` lays in here

Related to [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663243/could-not-create-task-this-and-base-files-have-different-roots) and [github thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105395)

Comment: I've set system environment variable PUB_CACHE (https://dart.dev/tools/pub/environment-variables) to the same drive with projects - and it worked (after clean)! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me, please check your IDE (android studio or Vs code ) **fultter and dart** extensions are **updated** , if not please update both then it will work , restart the IDE.

vs code> Extencions > flutter, Dart
Android Studio > File > settings > plugins > Flutter, Dart

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue recently. You may run upgrade in your terminal.

```
flutter pub upgrade
```