# PRDownloader not working even after implementing library. Unknown Reference for: PRDownloader in Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, android-download-manager

I implemented the PRDownloader in my gradle.

```
implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.6.0'
```

But when I type PRDownloader in my adapter class it gives me the error "Unknown Reference for: PRDownloader". It's the only error Android Studio gives me. I use `mavenCentral()` instead of `jcenter`. Maybe this could be causing some problems.

Comment: Please, add the *Logcat output* to your post which is gonna show us any errors or warnings for we can help you out with your issue.

Comment: My error comes up as I'm typing the code. The line is highlighted in red and gives me the Unknown reference error. I can't even run the Logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't version 0.6.0, the latest one's *0.5.0*.

Fix your code line to:

```kotlin
implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.5.0'
```

Also on the following Gradle script *build.gradle(Project: YOURPROJECTNAME)* the *jcenter()* repository in repositories statement:

```kotlin
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

**Warning:** *jcenter() repository's already deprecated for Android development. The  most ideal solution would be to look for some other similar library that offers support to mavenCentral() over one for avoiding deprecated repositories on your projects.*

**Reference:**

1. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mindorks.android/prdownloader?repo=jcenter
2. [JCenter deprecation; impact on Gradle and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66651640/jcenter-deprecation-impact-on-gradle-and-android)

Comment: It still doesn't work. It seems like it only works for jcenter repository and I use mavenCentral

Comment: I added to my answer how to add the *Jcenter repository* to your project. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback it. I've marked as answer as acceptable. However I do have a question. There's news that the jcenter() will be shutdown. Will this not cause problems in the future?

Comment: [Yep, the most correct would be to not use this library but some other which offfers support to the *mavenCentral( ) repository* over jcenter( ). Because the latter's already *deprecated* for Android development.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66651640/jcenter-deprecation-impact-on-gradle-and-android)

Comment: Thank you. By the looks of it I can still use jcenter until they move all the artifacts to mavenCentral. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.6.0'
implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.5.0'

Both Dependencies Not WORK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).