# We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-gradle-plugin

How can I update to latest version? I cannot find the latest [gradle-plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

**build.gradle(ExampleApp)**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        kotlin_serializtion_version = '1.5.21'
        kotlin_coroutines_version = "1.6.0"
        moshiVersion = "1.13.0"
        retrofit2_version = "2.9.0"
        okhttp3_version = "4.9.0"
        mockk_version = "1.12.2"
        picassoVersion = "2.71828"
        lifecycle_version = "2.5.0"
        koin_version = "3.2.0"
        barcode_scanner_version = "16.1.1"
        camerax_version = "1.0.0"
        camera_view_version = "1.0.0-alpha22"
        stripe_version = "19.1.0"
        jacoco_version = "0.8.7"
        room_version = "2.4.1"
        glide_version = "4.12.0"
        json_version = "20180813"
        kotlin_reflect_version = "1.6.10"
        compose_version = '1.2.0-rc03'
        espresso_version = '3.4.0'
        core_testing_version = '2.1.0'
        pdf_view_version = '3.2.0-beta.1'
        appboy_version = '21.0.0'
        mp_chart_version = "3.1.0"
        activity_compose = "1.5.0"
        compose_material3 = "1.0.0-alpha14"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_serializtion_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
}
apply from: "${rootDir}/config/sonarqube/sonarqube.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release' }
        maven { url 'https://mobile-sdk.jumio.com' }
        maven { url "https://appboy.github.io/appboy-android-sdk/sdk" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
```

**build.gradle(:app**)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        .....
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    sourceSets {
        test {
            java.srcDirs =
                [
                    "${project.projectDir}/src/test/java"
                ]
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.2.0"
        kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

    // kotlin atomic
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu:0.17.1'

    //Kotlin extensions library for Play Core
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'

    //Android Kotlin extensions
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0"

    //Unit test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:3.4.0'
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:${mockk_version}"
    testImplementation "org.json:json:$json_version"

    //Moshi (JSON parser)
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshiVersion"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion"

    //Retrofit2
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit2_version"

    //Paging 3
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.1"

    //Okhttp3
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3_version"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$okhttp3_version"

    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$kotlin_coroutines_version"

    //ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    //HTML parser
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'

    //Payments
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.1.0'
    implementation "com.stripe:stripe-android:$stripe_version"

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core"

    //Pager indicator
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.4'

    //Animations
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.2.2'
    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'

    //Loading images
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

    //View container which can wrap content
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'

    //Phone Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.7.0'

    //Video player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.3'

    //Dependency injection - Koin AndroidX Scope features
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-workmanager:$koin_version"
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test-junit4:$koin_version"
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test:$koin_version"

    //WorkManager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"

    // App Startup
    implementation "androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.0"

    //Progress button extension
    implementation 'com.github.razir.progressbutton:progressbutton:2.1.0'

    //PDF Viewer
    implementation "com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:$pdf_view_version"

    //Amplitude
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.25.2'

    //Salesforce chat
    implementation "com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:4.2.2"

    //Jumio
    implementation "com.jumio.android:core:3.9.2@aar"   // Jumio Core library
    implementation "com.jumio.android:nv:3.9.2@aar"     // Netverify library
    implementation "com.jumio.android:nv-barcode:3.9.2@aar"   // Barcode scanning
    implementation "com.jumio.android:nv-mrz:3.9.2@aar" // MRZ scanning

    //AppsFlyer
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'

    // Code Scanner & Camera
    implementation "com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:$barcode_scanner_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camera_view_version"

    // Braze (marketing push notifications)
    implementation "com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:$appboy_version"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"

    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$compose_material3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:$activity_compose"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test:$compose_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"

    // MP Charts
    implementation "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v$mp_chart_version"

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$core_testing_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"

    // Modules
    lintChecks project(':lint')

    // Miscellaneous
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_reflect_version"
    //Memory leak analysis - should only run in dev builds (devqaImplementation)
    //devqaImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.2'
}
```

Getting this warning message:

> We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33
>
> This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32
>
> This warning can be suppressed by adding `android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33` to this project's gradle.properties
>
> The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33

I updated already everything. What I am missing?

Answer (score 21):

As this message is just a warning, if your build is working fine, I'd suggest you to suppress the warning and don't update your Android Gradle plugin for now. Upgrading this plugin can bring you more trouble than good.

The Android Gradle plugin is published to the Google's Maven repository at [maven.google.com](https://maven.google.com).

The plugin's listing with all its versions can be found [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.android.tools.build#com.android.tools.build:gradle). You can pick a version of that list and test your build.

Just update the following line of your `build.gradle` file with the desired version:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:<NEW_VERSION_HERE>'
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind that you might need to update your Android Studio to the Beta or Canary channels do be able to use the newer versions of that plugin without problems.

Answer (score 11):

Add `android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33` to your `gradle.properties` file:

[image]

Comment: Suppressing a warning is not a solution though. Is it?

Comment: @ravi If you don't care about what it is warning you about, it's a solution.

Comment: @TylerH agreed but using the latest `compileSdk` is what we should be doing, isn't it?

Comment: It does not solves my problem

Answer (score 6):

Update plugins in build.gradle (project)

```
id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Android Studio, you usually upgrade from one Android SDK to the next (for example, from 33 to 34 at the time of this writing) using:

> Tools \ Android SDK Upgrade Assistant

This does not upgrade Gradle itself. To do so you need to run

> Tools \ AGP Upgrade Assistant

You'll get the option to specify the particular version you'll upgrade to

> Upgrade Android Gradle Plugin from version 7.4.2 to 8.2.2

Selecting the most recent (8.2.2 at the time of this writing), you'll find it's not quite as sizeable as an Android SDK upgrade.

> Gradle: download ... 192 MB

You'll receive a comforting message:

```
Sync succeeded
The upgraded project successfully synced with the IDE. You should test that the upgraded project builds and passes its tests successfully before making further changes.
The upgrade consisted of the following steps:
Upgrade AGP dependency from 7.4.2 to 8.2.2
Upgrade Gradle version to 8.2
Update default R8 processing mode
Enable buildConfig build feature
Preserve transitive R classes
Preserve constant R class values
```

You will not need to modify the string yourself. `<project>/build.gradle` is updated for you

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2'
    }
}
```

along with `<project>/gradle.properties` and `<project>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Subsequently you'd build as usual:

> Build \ Generate Signed Bundle APK

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in JetPack Compose .I tried by changing the compileSDK from 34 to 33 in the file name build.gradle.kts in android Studio and it worked.

```
android {
namespace = "com.example.smd_prep"
compileSdk = 34 //Changed this version from 33 to 34
```

Answer (score -3):

The follwing changes works for me:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

In ProjectStructure change the

Modules / Properties / Compile SDK version / 33

Modules / Default Config / Target SDK version / 33

Modules / Default Config / Min SDK version / 33

Than choose an emulator with API 33, example: Pixel 6 API 33

Comment: Why would you change the min SDK version.

Comment: Changing the min SDK to 33, is a very bad "solution"